# Jquery: Drop a draggable div to another div from subsequent parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

How can I able to drop or connect a draggable div to another div which is particularly located from subsequent parents? The code is shown below but unfortunately it is not working. When I drag the item to its designated position, it is reverting to its original position. Please help, thank you.

HTML

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <h1>List of Items</h1>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td id="wrapper" >
                        <div class="item" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="wrapper2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javasript

```
$('.item').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    snap: '#wrapper',
    containment: document.body,
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    appendTo: document.body
});

$('#wrapper2').droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below it is working. You should add JQuery UI for drag and drop. 
And give some width and height to div which you want to drag. So, it will display properly.

```js
$('.item').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    snap: '#wrapper',
    containment: document.body,
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    appendTo: document.body
});

$('#wrapper2').droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'));
    }
});
```

```css
.item{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <h1>List of Items</h1>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td id="wrapper" >
                        <div class="item" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="wrapper2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnxtthpo/1/)

Hope it helps.